# Remap Ctrl-ArrowKeys to switch between split buffers

Tags: vim

How can I remap `Ctrl-ArrowKeys` to move between split buffers, like I can with `<C-w> <ArrowKeys>`?

Right now `<C-Right>` deletes until the end of line and goes into insert mode - which is not what i prefer (I use `C` for this) and would be happy to get rid of this behavior.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
nnoremap <silent> <C-Right> <c-w>l
nnoremap <silent> <C-Left> <c-w>h
nnoremap <silent> <C-Up> <c-w>k
nnoremap <silent> <C-Down> <c-w>j
```

It must be said that not all mappings work on all terminal, so you mileage may vary. This is working well with gvim.

Comment: I use these mappings with the addition of mapping <C-S-ARROW> to move the splits with  

`    nnoremap <silent> <C-S-UP> <C-W>K`

This makes it much easier to get the split windows where you want them

Comment: @Sam Brinck: I like that idea. I do to not reach for the arrow keys, but since I move windows so infrequently that it might be worth considering.

Comment: You are right - works on gvim (macVim), but it does not work in terminal. Do you have any suggestions how to make it work in OS X Lion, and vim 7.3.237?

Comment: @sumpfgottheit: I do not have a fix for lion's terminal, but for more information on mapping keycodes in vim take a look at this vim wiki article: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_fast_keycodes_in_terminal_Vim

Comment: @sumpfgottheit Nine years late but for others with this problem, try disabling the keyboard shortcuts to move left/right a space in system preferences > keyboard > shortcuts > mission control.

Answer (score 1):

I also use those mapping when working with spli windows:

```
" To move between buffers and maximise the selected one
map <C-J> <C-W>j<C-W>_
map <C-K> <C-W>k<C-W>_
```

Combined with

```
" This sets the minimum window height to N
set wmh=0
```

It's pretty good.
I have been used this for a while now and I'm completely addicted!

Comment: You coulduse: `:set winheight=999` and this automatically maxes up the current split whenever getting the focus.

Comment: Yes, but I also need to be able to keep 2 splits at the quite often ;). The bindings above let you choose wether you want to maximize or not!